# python script - problem in calling a function

Tags: python, python-3.x, function

currently i'am working on a project which is a script that generates a random questions from defined list and asking the user to but weights to these questions and finally returns a dictionary showing each question with its weight

the problem is i'am not sure where to call a function in the main, and also the script returns an empty dictionary!

can anyone help me to solve this

````
import random

dict = {
    "easy":["q1", "q2", "q3"],
    "mid":['q4', 'q5', 'q6', 'q7'],
    "hard":['q8', 'q9', 'q10', 'q11', 'q12']
}



tamplate = []
def make_random_tamp():
    # print(random.choices(quistions))
    i = 0
    e = 0
    m = 0
    h = 0
    random_easy_q = ''
    random_mid_q = ''
    random_hard_q = ''
    while (i < 6):
        while(e < 2):
            random_easy_q = random.choices(dict["easy"])
            if random_easy_q not in tamplate:
                tamplate.append(random_easy_q)
                e+=1
                i+=1
            continue
        while(m < 2):
            random_mid_q = random.choices(dict["mid"])
            if random_mid_q not in tamplate:
                tamplate.append(random_mid_q)
                m+=1
                i+=1
            continue
        while(h < 2):
            random_hard_q = random.choices(dict["hard"])
            if random_hard_q not in tamplate:
                tamplate.append(random_hard_q)
                h+=1
                i+=1
            continue
    return tamplate



make_random_tamp()

w_quistion = {}

def wheights(tamplate, dict):
    for i in tamplate:
        j=0
        if tamplate[j] in dict["easy"]:
            w_quistion[input("please enter wheight from 1-5 to this quistion :")] = tamplate[j]
            j+=1
        elif tamplate[j] in dict["mid"]:
            w_quistion[input("please enter a wheight from 6-15 to this quistion :")] = tamplate[j]
            j+=1
        elif tamplate[j] in dict["hard"]:
            w_quistion[input("please enter a weight from 15-25 to this quistion :")] = tamplate[j]
            j+=1

    return w_quistion




print(wheights(tamplate, dict)) ```
````

Answer (score 0):

There are two major problems in your implementation:

1. You define `tamplate` as an empty list but the return value from the function `make_random_tamp` is not assigned to `tamplate`.
2. Your dictionary values are list objects so you need to use `extend()` to add the elements in the main list else it will be list of lists.

```py
import random

def make_random_tamp():
    i = 0
    e = 0
    m = 0
    h = 0
    random_easy_q = ''
    random_mid_q = ''
    random_hard_q = ''
    tamplate = []
    while (i < 6):
        while(e < 2):
            random_easy_q = random.choices(dict_ob["easy"])
            if random_easy_q not in tamplate:
                tamplate.extend(random_easy_q)  # use extend instead of append
                e+=1
                i+=1
            continue
        while(m < 2):
            random_mid_q = random.choices(dict_ob["mid"])
            if random_mid_q not in tamplate:
                tamplate.extend(random_mid_q)
                m+=1
                i+=1
            continue
        while(h < 2):
            random_hard_q = random.choices(dict_ob["hard"])
            if random_hard_q not in tamplate:
                tamplate.extend(random_hard_q)
                h+=1
                i+=1
            continue

    return tamplate


def wheights(tamplate, dict_ob):
    w_quistion = {} # create local object here
    # other code here
    return w_quistion


tamplate = make_random_tamp()
print(wheights(tamplate, dict_ob))
```

Other than the above problems, you should avoid using keywords like `dict` for object names and the dictionary `w_quistion` could be declared as a local object in the `wheights()` function.

Note: I have removed some portion of the code for brevity.